# Syntax error when trying to build client/server connections

Tags: python

I am reading a book on Black Hat programming with Python and I am currently getting a syntax error while creating a client/server connection. I have checked the book a few times to make sure I had no errors and I believe I do not.

Code:

```
print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)
```

Anybody have any ideas? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: That code is for Python 2, an obsolete version of the language, and you're most likely using Python 3. Try `print(f"[*] Listening on {bind_ip}:{bind_port}")` instead. If the whole book uses Python 2, you'd better find a newer edition.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. The book does use python 2 I thought that when I changed kali Linux from python 3 to python 2 it would make it so it wouldn't cause any problems, but I must have either done that wrong or it may be a problem with wing ide which I am creating my programs on. You are right, should probably find a book that uses python 3 if I cant fix it another way.

Comment: Don't start a new project in Python 2 anymore!

Comment: I'll echo what @KlausD. said. Python 2 should ***only*** be used for maintaining legacy applications that, for whatever reason, can't be moved to Python 3. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Comment: Ya you guys are right. I was thinking that I would just finish the book then learn all the differences after but I should probably just focus on building clients and servers as well as networking stuff for now and just find a new book. Thanks for feedback.